# WPF - Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top binding not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to bind border's `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`, there is no issue in binding but the problem is its not updating its value. For the first step it works great but its not working for other steps.

```
<Border 
   Name="helpBox" 
   CornerRadius="10" 
   Panel.ZIndex="50"
   Background="Black" 
   BorderBrush="Black" 
   BorderThickness="0"
   Height="Auto" 
   Width="580"
   MouseLeftButtonDown="helpBox_MouseLeftButtonDown"
   MouseLeftButtonUp="helpBox_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
   MouseMove="helpBox_MouseMove"
   Canvas.Left="{Binding CurrentTour.CurrentStep.HelpBoxLeft}"
   Canvas.Top="{Binding CurrentTour.CurrentStep.HelpBoxTop}"/>`
```

Comment: Where is this `Border` places?

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint in the `HelpBoxLeft` property in your code so see if your binding is working properly.

Comment: Try adding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the bindings

Comment: @SpookKruger Why TwoWay? That doesn't make any sense. And PropertyChanged is already the default value for UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: Do the HelpBoxLeft and HelpBoxTop properties implement any property change mechanism? You would typically implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx) interface in the class that declares the properties (i.e. the class that CurrentStep is an instance of).

Comment: @Clemens I absolutely agree,the PropertyChanged is unnecessary, i just found that it gives me better perspective in understanding the problem. unfortunately i don't have any more clues than that on the screen. I am just trying to give a hint at perhaps propagating the value of the binding back to the business model to ensure that values perceived and updated are correct.

Comment: No, its not working by doing its Bindind Mode="Two way"